# Add Motion Blur to SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-animation

Is there any way to add a MotionBlur effect in Swift 3? I am using sprite kit in Xcode 8

Comment: possibly with a shader, or coreanimation filter... not sure about performance though...

Comment: I found an example of using it in coreanimation: https://github.com/fastred/MotionBlur

Comment: updated tags for better visibility.. may do a bounty on this one.. Also, what specifically are you trying to blur? The whole screen? Or just certain sprite(s)?